# How do I programmatically (c#) validate drive letters for international cultures such as Chinese?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, validation, internationalization

**Background:**

I am trying to validate a path that may not actually exist. So, I can't validate it using "Directory.Exists()" method. Also, the code may be run on a different machine.I just want to know what's valid and what's invalid. I researched and found that this is lot more complicated than I originally imagined. It would have been lot simpler if Microsoft had given a method for this.

I soon realised that methods such as Path.GetInvalidPathChars() and Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars() have very limited value. If you validate using GetInvalidPathChars(), it allows letters such as "*" and "?", which are not actually valid as directory name or file name. GetInvalidFileNameChars() is a better option. But, it doesn't allow colon (':'), which is actually a valid character only if it is immediately after the drive letter. Besides, there are few more rules that dictate that a folder name cannot have all characters as dots ('.'). Similarly, a directory cannot have some reserved words such as LPT1 to LPT9 or COM1 to COM9. The complete list of rules is documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

So, to validate the path, I am splitting the path into 2 parts -

- root part using Path.GetPathRoot() method and validate that separately
- the remaining path - This is further split using Path.DirectorySeparatorChar and then I validate each directory name individually using a complex algorithm. (Once complete, I will post that code later).

**Main Question**

I want to validate root path by checking that the drive letter is valid. I know you can only have drives from A: to Z: on English cultures. But how can I validate that for international cultures such as Chinese or Japanese? I couldn't find any documentation for list of valid drive letters for German or Chinese machines. Do those systems allow other Unicode characters as drive letters?

Comment: Have you tried searching your strings using culture invariance? I've done some Regex'ing with Hebrew and Arabic texts before, and IIRC that worked for me.

Comment: Why don't you ask the file system? In other words: Don't try to validate anything ahead of time. Just use the path as is. The I/O API will let you know when the input is wrong. Anyway, you already know the answer to your main question. Drive letters are an artifact, carried over from DOS. DOS predates Unicode. (Keep in mind, that you can reference volumes without using a drive letter.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple: A-Z are the only valid drive letters, no matter what the culture is.
But you can of course have a path without a drive letter.

In general you don't need to worry about the culture when dealing with path names. A folder uses Unicode and is accessible to all users regardless of locale.

But there are a lot of other very big problems to solve.

I would say: this is not possible.
A full explanation why is to much for a Stackoverflow answer.
But think about this: I might have a network share share mapped to a drive letter. That might be a Linux or Mac folder shared with Samba. So you sundenly have to account for all the limitations of those OSes, the exact file system on that machine, and the limitations of the sharing protocol.
Or think a Windows machine sharing a FAT32 file system. Or even a FAT16 one, that does not support Unicode, nor long file names.

There are many other problems, even for local drives.
But, as I said, too much for this answer.

Comment: Thanks. You have answered my main question about drive letters. As far as paths without drive letter such as - "\\ServerName\ShareName\folder" - I validate that separately. My assumption is very simple - The OS of the server on the network doesn't matter. My application only runs on Windows and any path will always be presented in a format that Microsoft allows as Path. I am not much worried about additional restrictions on non-Microsoft platforms or hidden drives, because for my typical requirement, they are border cases and its ok, even if the validation doesn't support 1% of restrictions.

Comment: "any path will always be presented in a format that Microsoft allows as Path": true. But the underlaying technology might only support a subset of what windows can. Even pure Windows, if the local disk is FAT16 (as an extreme case) then it does not support Unicode. So your code might say a path with Greek characters is valid, but the file system will not allow it. So it fails. Edge cases, true. But it is always good know what the limitations are. For instance "NTFS, local disk only" (although there are some traps even there) :-)